# Entering Project Number not working/But Selecting project from drop down list work properly

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, navbar

when try to select project by entering number its pop up the MsgBox, but its working properly when click the Drop Down list.

[image]

When add project number its select full name and everything but when hit open project its pop up MsgBox as attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If so, `GetProjectID` returns `-1` which should have been easy to debug.

Use the *AfterUpdate* event of `ProjectNo` to call:

```
modGlobals.SetProjectDetails ProjectNo.Value
```